# PHP/MYSQL - Save table fields as individual string variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cookies

I am attempting to retrieve the names of different columns of a MYSQL table and then save them as individual string variables from which I set as cookies. The problem is that all of the recipes are saved in a single element in an array. It would even be helpful if I could save each field as a separate object in an array. Moreover, some of the field names may contain blank characters (e.g. spaces). I honestly am not too sure how to approach this, however I have attempted in my simplified code below:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "db_name";

$table_id = "table_name";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_public_tables);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table_id`";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $field_array = implode(" ", $row[0]);

    setcookie('selected_field_array_cookie', $field_array);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I am looking for an output where I am able to print a specific field name on a html page. For example:

```
echo $field3;
```

Thanks for your consideration. Answers in any form are welcome although preferably using PHP/MYSQL/JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you're looking for:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "db_name";
$table_id = "table_name";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if(!$conn) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table_id`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$field_array = array();
$index = 1;
$omitted_fields = array('id', 'reg_date');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if(!in_array($row[0], $omitted_fields)) {
        $field_array['field' . $index] = $row[0];
        setcookie('field' . $index, $row[0]);
        extract($field_array);
        $index += 1;
    }
}

echo $field1 . "<br>";
echo $field2 . "<br>";
echo $field3 . "<br>";
echo $_COOKIE['field1'] . "<br>";
echo $_COOKIE['field2'] . "<br>";
echo $_COOKIE['field3'] . "<br>";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks @Perumal93 I found a similar solution earlier which I was going to post tomorrow (computer is shutdown). I really appreciate the help 